# Force array instead of matrix in J for "i."

Tags: j

The `i.` primitive produces a list of integers:

```
   i. 10
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

If I want to produce several short lists in a row, I do this:

```
   ;i."0 each [ 2 3 4
0 1 0 1 2 0 1 2 3
```

(the result I want)

Boxing (that `each`) is a crutch here, because without it, `i."0` produces a matrix.

```
   i."0 [ 2 3 4
0 1 0 0
0 1 2 0
0 1 2 3
```

(the result I don't want)

Is there a better way to not have `i."0` format the output to a matrix, but an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I believe you can't do any better than your current solution. There is no way for `i."0` to return a vector.

The `"0` adverb forces `i.` to accept scalars, and `i.` returns vectors.  `i.` has no way of knowing that your input was a vector rather than a scalar.  According to [The J primer](http://jsoftware.com/help/primer/result_shape.htm) the result shape is the concatenation of the frame of the argument and the result.

The shortest "box-less" solution I've found so far is

```
(*@$"0~#&,i."0) 2 3 4
```

which is still longer than just using `;i. each 2 3 4`

Comment: I was thinking of something with the `@` family to force raze (`;`) or ravel (`,`) with every result. Or something similar.

Comment: @MPelletier But you can't do it inside the `"0`; the result will be a matrix no matter what; and you can't do it outside, since by then the damage is done.

Comment: Grrr... Is there some other way to call `i.` than with `"0`, then? I'm not adamant about "0, just as long as I get my array.

Comment: @mpelletier alas, calling `i.` with a nonscalar doesn't do what we want here.  I've updated my answer with a slightly shorter function but I doubt there is a simpler solution than your origial attempt.  Note that you don't need `"0` when using `each`

Comment: Oh yeah, Why the heck did I use `"0` *and* `each` in the first place? Thanks, sverre!